# How to remove indicator from gnome-shell panel

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard, indicator, gnome-panel

How to remove the keyboard indicator from gnome-shell in Ubuntu 14.04? I hate everything about it

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Icon Hider gnome-shell extension to hide icons from gnome-shell pannel.

[image]

Install it from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/). Once installed disable keyboard in it.

Answer (score 1):

From http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/remove-keyboard-indicator-ubuntu/, go to System Settings and uncheck the box:

[image: Text Entry]